# FastLED.h blocks ezButton.h

Tags: c++, c, button, arduino, led

I'm using Arduino to control a project which contains addressable LEDs and buttons.
The libraries I'm using are in the title.
For an unknown reason, when I use each code separately everything works fine, but when I combine them the FastLED library blocks the button reading and causes weird things - like giving double press, or stop doing other things.

How can I fix the issue? (I tried to eliminate the delay(), but it wasn't helpful)
Thanks in advance!

```
/*
  Author: Yuval Kedar - KD Technology
  Instagram: https://www.instagram.com/kd_technology/
  Date: Oct 19
  Dev board: Arduino Uno
  
    There are two button types: Red and Blue.
    Red btn = -1
    Blue btn = +1

    On the machine's background there is an LED matrix which shows the user's progress.
    There are 4 levels (square frames) until one reaches the core and wins.

    The trick? The floor, which includes the buttons, is spinning.
*/

#include <FastLED.h>
#include <ezButton.h>
#include "Arduino.h"

#define WINNING_SENSOR_PIN (12)
#define LED_DATA_PIN (6)
#define BLUE_BTN_PIN (A0)
#define RED_BTN_PIN (A3)

#define SERIAL_BAUDRATE (115200)
#define NUM_LEDS (64)
#define LED_BRIGHTNESS (200)
#define WINNING_FX_TIME (1000)

ezButton blue_btn(BLUE_BTN_PIN);
ezButton red_btn(RED_BTN_PIN);
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

uint8_t score = 0;
uint8_t last_score = 0;
uint8_t level[] = {0, 28, 48, 60, 63};  //levels 0 to 4

void level_up(uint8_t led_num) {
    uint8_t start_point = 0;
    if (led_num == level[1]) start_point = 0;   //up from level 0 to 1
    if (led_num == level[2]) start_point = 28;  //up from level 1 to 2
    if (led_num == level[3]) start_point = 48;  //up from level 2 to 3
    if (led_num == level[4]) start_point = 60;  //...

    for (uint8_t current_pixel = start_point; current_pixel < led_num; current_pixel++) {
        leds[current_pixel] = CRGB::Blue;
        FastLED.show();
        delay(50);
    }
    delay(2500); //debounce
}

void level_down(uint8_t led_num) {  //clear prev level's frame and do the opposite direction effect with red color
    uint8_t start_point = 0;
    if (led_num == level[0]) start_point = 28;  //down from level 1 to 0
    if (led_num == level[1]) start_point = 48;  //down from level 2 to 1
    if (led_num == level[2]) start_point = 60;  //down from level 3 to 2
    if (led_num == level[3]) start_point = 63;  //...

    for (int8_t i = start_point - 1; i > led_num; i--) {
        leds[i] = CRGB::Red;
        FastLED.show();
        delay(50);
    }
    for (int8_t i = start_point - 1; i > led_num; i--) {
        leds[i] = CRGB::Black;
        FastLED.show();
    }
    delay(2500); //debounce
}

void fadeall() {
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
        leds[i].nscale8(250);
    }
}

void winning() {
    static uint8_t hue = 0;
    for(uint8_t x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        for(int8_t i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
            leds[i] = CHSV(hue++, 255, 255);
            FastLED.show(); 
            fadeall();
            // delay(10);
        }
        for(int8_t i = (NUM_LEDS)-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            leds[i] = CHSV(hue++, 255, 255);
            FastLED.show();
            fadeall();
            // delay(10);
        }
    }
    
}

void reset_game() {
    score = 0;
    last_score = 4;
    digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, LOW);
    FastLED.clear();
    FastLED.show();}

void winning_check() {
    (score == 4) ? analogWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, 175) : digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, LOW);
}

void update_score() {
    if (blue_btn.isPressed()) {
        Serial.println("+PLUS+");
        if (score++ >= 4) score = 4;
    }

    if (red_btn.isPressed()) {
        Serial.println("-MINUS-");
        if (score-- <= 0) score = 0;
    }

    if (score == 0){
        if (last_score == 1) level_down(level[0]);
        last_score = 0;
        digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, LOW);
    }
    else if (score == 1) {
        if (last_score == 0) level_up(level[1]);    // if last_score was 0 make the blue effect because level is up
        if (last_score == 2) level_down(level[1]);  // if last_score was 2 make the red effect because level is down
        last_score = 1;
        digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, LOW);
    }
    else if (score == 2) {
        if (last_score == 1) level_up(level[2]);
        if (last_score == 3) level_down(level[2]);
        last_score = 2;
        digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, LOW);
    }
    else if (score == 3) {
        if (last_score == 2) level_up(level[3]);
        if (last_score == 4) level_down(level[3]);
        last_score = 3;
        digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, LOW);
    }
    else if (score == 4) {
        winning_check();
        // winning();  //this func makes issue when using ezButton.h. It calls "show" too many times.
        reset_game();
    }
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(SERIAL_BAUDRATE);

    pinMode(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, LOW);

    blue_btn.setDebounceTime(150);
    red_btn.setDebounceTime(150);

    FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, LED_DATA_PIN>(leds, NUM_LEDS);  // GRB ordering is assumed
    FastLED.setBrightness(LED_BRIGHTNESS);
    FastLED.clear();
    FastLED.show();


    Serial.println(F(
        "_______________________________\n"
        "\n"
        "   G e a r   M a c h i n e     \n"
        "_______________________________\n"
        "\n"
        "   ~ Made by KD Technology ~   \n"
        "\n"));
}

void loop() {
    blue_btn.loop();
    red_btn.loop();
    Serial.println(score);

    update_score();
    FastLED.show();
}
```

Comment: do not do `show()` on the leds so often, update all and then show all the changes. also - doing a delay of 2.5s is sure to affect how/when the button states are read...

Comment: When I do the 2.5 sec delay, the buttons are not suppose to be pressed so I don't realy care (unless it affects the code and making problem).

About the show(), I'm making effects that require an update every single pixel change.
How can I do it else way?

Comment: your program spends (2.5s + 10ms*number of leds) updating the leds, and then probably 1ms or so checking the buttons. That's probably why buttons appear blocked...

Comment: I just checked, and if I call show() only once and delete the delay() it works good.
Could you please show me how can I call show() only once and still get the effect I want?

Comment: Since I do now know what kind of effects you are after, I can not do that. But you could try making sure it only updates the LEDs if there is a change to the data, instead of always doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that, you used the [delay()](https://arduinogetstarted.com/reference/arduino-delay) function. If you use the delay, some pressed events will be missed, not only for ezButton, but also for any kind of button press implementation. The ezButton already has the internal debounce function.